# Python packaging - Proper usage of the tests folder with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pip, python-unittest, python-packaging

I'm experimenting with packaging some Pythons projects and have followed [this](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) guide. The anonymized file tree can be seen below. The `toml` file is a barebones one from the tutorial modified appropriately. Building and uploading works well. So far so good.

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── mymodule
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── main.py
└── tests
```

My next intended step is to package an older smaller well behaving project which includes a test suite written with `unittest`. Simplified structure below.

```
.
├── mymodule
│   ├── submoduleA
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └ foo.py
│   ├── submoduleB
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └ bar.py
│   ├── baz.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── test_submoduleA.py
    └── test_submoduleB.py
```

This is where my progress grinds to a halt.
There are many different ways to skin a cat but none directly involves `unittest` as far as I can tell. I have opted to go ahead by using `tox` to call the former.

Similarly when I have a look at different Python project repos the structure under `tests` seem to differ a bit.

**End intent/wish:** Convert said older project to a packagable one, editing the tests as little as possible, and using the tests for testing while developing *and* to do basic tests on the target device later.

**Questions:**

- What is the purpose of the `tests` folder? Eg to run tests while developing files in `src`, to test the built package and/or to verify a package works once installed?
- Is it possible to use the `pyproject.toml` file with `unittest`?

Comment: This question is out of scope for StackOverflow (because it is opinion based; "_many different ways to skin a cat_" as you said)... :/ -- You might want to break it down into multiple focused questions, with a [mre] of what you have tried and blocks you.

Comment: ***Q:*** "_What is the purpose of the tests folder? Eg to run tests while developing files in src, to test the built package and/or to verify a package works once installed?_" ***A:*** Both. -- ***Q:*** "_What are the best practices re. the tests folder?_"***A:*** Place the unit (and functional) test scripts in there. I prefer to name it `test` (make it easier with _setuptools_). Do not put `__init__.py` in there. -- ***Q:*** "_Is it possible to use the pyproject.toml file with unittest?_" ***A:*** Yes. -- ***Q:*** "_Are there any good project-examples for me to study?_" ***A:*** For sure :D